# Combinatorics: how many unique polygons can be drawn using up to p points along a circle?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I am faced with the following problem:

> Let p ≥ 3 be a prime number, and mark p points at equal distance on
>   the circumference of a circle like in the pictures below (where p =
>   7). We can trace polygons by choosing a certain amount of those points
>   as vertices, and connecting them with non-intersecting straight lines.

With three parts:

> a) How many different polygons can we form  if we consider that a different choice of vertices leads to a different polygon?

This is straightforward: you can have polygons with three vertices, 4 vertices […] up until p vertices, and the amount of polygons you can draw of a given number of vertices k is $p \choose k$. Hence the answer is ${p \choose 3} + {p \choose 4} + {...} + {p \choose p-1} + {p \choose p}$

> b) How many different polygons can we form if we count all different rotations of the same polygon as a single polygon?

Well, any given polygon can be rotated up to $p-1$ times. Hence each polygon counted from a) is actually being counted 7 times. We adjust for this by dividing through the answer in a) by p, and get the answer as $\frac{p \choose 3}{p} + \frac{p \choose 4}{p} + {...} + \frac{p \choose p-1}{p} + \frac{p \choose p}{p} = \frac{p \choose 3}{p} + \frac{p \choose 4}{p} + {...} + \frac{p \choose p-2}{p} + 1 + 1$.

I think all the above makes sense, but I am struggling with the third part:

> c) How many different polygons can we form if we count all isometric polygons (all rotations and reflections of the same polygon) as the same ?

[image]

And I don't know how to proceed from here. I'm guessing there has to be some pattern to the number of reflections+rotations that any polygon of k vertices has along p points. However, I've tried playing around with small examples and I can't seem to find any generalizable pattern, and I've been stumped for longer than I'd like to admit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reworded: How many [necklaces and bracelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) (*necklaces for part b and bracelets for part c*) of length $p$ with $p$ prime can be made with beads of two possible colors such that there are at least three beads of the first color used.

Comment: Almost exactly the same question was [posted just a week ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525478) but then deleted when I answered it. a) Does this happen to be from an ongoing contest? If so, are you aware of the [contest problem policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774)? b) If it isn't, and I post an answer, do you promise not to delete the question? :-)

Comment: @joriki it is not a contest problem. I haven't seen the other post / don't see why it was deleted. This is a problem from a university class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polygons are in correspondence with the subsets of the vertices with at least $3$ elements. Thus, as JMoravitz noted in a comment, this can be viewed as counting binary [necklaces and bracelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) of length $p$ with at least three beads of the first colour, where the first colour signifies a vertex that’s included and the second colour signifies a vertex that isn’t included in the polygon.

For part a), there is no symmetry to take into account, so the result is just $2^p-\binom p2-\binom p1-\binom p0$. (Your result is correct, you just didn't use the fact that $\sum_k\binom pk=2^k$, the total number of subsets of the set of $k$ vertices.)

For part b), with rotational symmetry, you failed to properly account for the fact that the polygon that includes all vertices has only one rotational equivalent, not $p$. Your final result is correct, but only because you replaced $\frac{\binom pp}p=\frac1p$ by $1$. If you count correctly, you have $2^p-\binom p2-\binom p1-\binom p0-\binom pp$ polygons that form classes of $p$ rotational equivalents each, and $\binom pp=1$ polygon that’s in a class of its own, so the total count is

$$
\frac{2^p-\binom p2-\binom p1-\binom p0-\binom pp}p+1=\frac{2^p-2}p-\frac{p+1}2\;.
$$

For part c), with rotational and reflectional symmetry, it becomes easier to perform the count using [Burnside’s lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma). The general result is given in the Wikipedia article linked to above. In your case, since $p$ is an odd prime, there are

\begin{eqnarray}
B_2(p)
&=&
\frac12N_2(p)+\frac12\cdot2^{\frac{p+1}2}
\\
&=&
\frac12\cdot\frac1p\left(1\cdot2^p+(p-1)\cdot2^1\right)+2^{\frac{p-1}2}
\\
&=&
\frac{2^{p-1}-1}p+1+2^{\frac{p-1}2}
\end{eqnarray}

binary bracelets. We need to subtract the $1$ bracelet with $0$ elements of the second colour, the $1$ bracelet with $1$ element of the second colour and the $\frac{p-1}2$ bracelets with $2$ elements of the second colour, so the number of polygons up to rotations and reflections is

$$
\frac{2^{p-1}-1}p+2^{\frac{p-1}2}-\frac{p+1}2\;.
$$